# gps trips saved as two timesdelta columns.My question is how to convert timesdelta in date or at least to a string?

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin

Noob here.
I am doing ssh into a php server and I must do python server which is using mysql database from there. My start and stop times are saved as timesdelta which makes no sense but I got to work around it.I want to convert timesdelta into date or at least a string.

So I have trip_date which is object "2018-04-23', start_time which is timedelta64[ns] and end_time also timedelta64[ns]
I need to turn somehow start_time and end_time into time and joint it with date in one column so I can do a prediction model.

I tried:

```
 df["start_time"] = df["start_time"].str.split(" ")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandasdf['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'], format='%H:%M:%S ', utc=True)
ValueError: time data 49080000000000 does not match format '%H:%M:%S ' (match)
for stuff in df['start_time']:
    stuff = str(stuff )
```

Nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

The `stuff=str(stuff)` part won't do what you expected. If you want to convert timesdelta to a string, you should stock `str(stuff)` in another variable. You can try this for exemple:

```
time_str=[]
for stuff in df['start_time']:
    time_str.append(str(stuff))
```

You can checkout the type by using `print(type(time_str[0]))`